# In Google Sheets, create a hyperlink in a cell that is clickable directly. No need to hover for popup link

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working with a sheet with many rows and next to a column that has Amazon ASIN's (just as an example), I want to have a column next to it that builds a hyperlink so that you can easily jump to the Amazon page.

I have a formula set up to do this with some additional functions to ensure if an ASIN isn't present, it just leaves a blank in the 2nd column.

`=IF(ISTEXT(B4), hyperlink("https://www.amazon.com/dp/" & B4, "Go"))`

This works, except that the link is not directly clickable in the cell. When you hover over the cell, a popup appears that indicates the link and an icon that shows you it will open in another window. It's this popup that I would rather eliminate and I would like to make the cell directly clickable.

[image: Image showing popup I would love to eliminate]

Comment: I think that this should be pointed to Google as a feature request, unless you are open to alternatives, in such case this question is too broad/opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe is by design of the Google Sheets web interface. Users cannot change it.

The only other way of opening a hyperlink in a cell is to press Alt-Enter when the cell is selected. This may be preferable to mouse navigation for keyboard-oriented users.